# Inserting jQuery results into SQL

Tags: jquery, sql

I have a timepicker jQuery script set up to let the user select a time. How can I convert the input into a format that I can insert into a databse (using an SQL INSERT statement)?

Here is my script and my sql command:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#FromTime").timepicker({ 'step': 15 });
        $('#ToTime').timepicker({
            'step': 15,
            'showDuration': true
        });
        $('#FromTime').on('changeTime', function () {
            $('#ToTime').timepicker('option', { 'minTime': $(this).val() });
        });

    });
```

I am looking for the FromTime and ToTime to be inserted into SQL via an insert such as...

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into TABLE (FromTimeSQL) Values (FromTime)", con)
```

Comment: Which server side language are you using?

Comment: what are you using for the backend of your server? asp.net? C#? php?

Comment: using asp.net for my language

Comment: any help on this from anyone else?